# How to customize datagridview with empty rows and set the data source without considering empty rows?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, dataadapter

I am using `vb 2010` and I have a Datagridview.

I want to set the data source to get the benefits of dataAdapter and dataTable, but the problem is my Datagridview should have 20 empty rows just for styling and I am pretty sure that adding them is not the best solution.

This is because they are used only for the style and I want them to be ignored by the application and the user should not use them. I do not know if I described as well as it should be.

I tried to add those 20 rows, but I couldn't use the dataAdapter as it sees those rows as empty which is different about what it sees in the database or dataset.

As I mentioned there should be a better solution then what I'm using as I have to do everything manually, insert, update, etc ...

Comment: That is going against convention and I would not recommend you do it. Why is it so important to display it that way? Any user who has ever used a grid is already familiar with how they normally work. If you lock the size of the grid you might be able to add a `BackgroundImage` that appears to be a set of rows but that is a terrible idea forget I said it.

Comment: There are almost certainly ways to get your grid to look the way you want but you're not going to be able to bind the grid and have rows that don't correspond to items in the data source. You're either going to have to forgo binding or else create one or more custom cell types and replace some of the auto-generated cells with instances of that type. Forgoing binding doesn't mean that you can't still use a data adapter and a `DataTable`. It just means an extra step of loading the data from the `DataTable` into the grid and, possibly, back again.

Comment: Background image is one solution but it is not a good idea, I saw many applications have those rows and data binding is not a problem to them, I am new to data grids I don't know why options like this are not included in .net. i am pretty sure that there is something missing.